# Proof of Cancellation Law for Multiplication in N (Induction)

Tags: induction, algebraic-number-theory

I'm struggling a bit to prove the Cancellation Law for multiplication for the Natural numbers, using induction.

So far I have this:

---

Having $a, b \in N$ e $S = \lbrace c \in N | a \cdot c = b \cdot c \longrightarrow a = b \rbrace$

We know that $1 \in S$, since $a \cdot 1 = a = b = b \cdot 1$, 0 is not the base case because even if $a \neq b$, $a \cdot 0 = 0 = b \cdot 0$.

Using $k \in S$, by definition $a \cdot k = b \cdot k \longrightarrow a=b$, we have to show that $k' \in S$

Assuming that $a \cdot k' = b \cdot k'$, we have $a \cdot k + a = b \cdot k + b$, and I don't know where to go from here.

---

I tried using something like [this](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/nt/nthw01a.pdf), however I'm still stuck.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

The key is Trichotomy! $\forall x \forall y (x < y \lor y <x \lor x=y)$

Also, your theorem should be that $\forall a \forall b \forall c (c \not = 0 \rightarrow (a \cdot c = b \cdot c \rightarrow a = b))$

That is, for any $c \not = 0$:

If $a < b$ you can show that $a \cdot c < b \cdot c$, and for $b < a$ you have $b \cdot c < a \cdot c$, so if $a\cdot c = b \cdot c$ you must have $a=b$

Comment: This has already been proven on the previous question, as the commutative property and other basic stuff.

Comment: @MikaelMello Great! So then do you see how to use those for your proof?

Comment: I added an edit about the base case being 0, and no, I don't see where I could use the cancellation law for addition, can I assume that $a = b$ or something like that?

Comment: @MikaelMello No, you need to *show * that $a=b$, assuming $a\cdot k' = b \cdot k'$, using the inductive hypothesis that  $a\cdot k = b \cdot k \rightarrow a=b$

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying, however after assuming that $a \cdot k' = b \cdot k'$, the only step I can think of is $a \cdot k + a = b \cdot k + b$, and then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @MikaelMello Do you have trichotomy: $\forall a \forall b (a < b \lor b < a \lor a=b)$?

Comment: Yes, it's been proven too.

Comment: @MikaelMello Oh wait ... this rings a bell now ... (I went through this some years ago)... if I remember correctly, with induction you indeed get stuck ... but you don't need induction: if $a < b$ then $a \cdot k < b \cdot k$ for any $k \not = 0$ (which is something you actually need to add to your theorem: it only holds for $k \not = 0$!). Same for $b > a$.

Comment: So it is basically impossible to prove it by induction? That explains why even my teacher failed at that, I'll try with proof by contradiction, thanks.

Comment: @MikaelMello Ha ha, yes, it's all coming back now:  I tried using induction myself and was baffled I couldn't get it. But yes, just use Trichotomy, that should work.  Sorry to send you on the wrong path before!

Comment: @MikaelMello So did that work for you?

Comment: Yes, I used the trichotomy law and the usual order compatibility (I guess that's the name in English) which says $a < b \longrightarrow a \cdot c < b \cdot c$. I have to prove the latter in the next question, but that's another problem I guess.

Comment: @MikaelMello  Hmm, is that is left for the *next* question, maybe for this problem it is enough to show that if $a \not = b$, then $a \cdot c \not = b \cdot c$ (for $c \not = 0$ of course!) ... but I think for that you still need trichotomy. And you definitely want to use trichotomy for that latter problem.

Comment: That's how I did, so if $a \neq b$, then $a < b$ or $b < $, using that compatibility I proved that $a \cdot c < b \cdot c$ or $a \cdot c > b \cdot c$. I don't know how to prove what  you said via other means. By the way the way I did (even using the next question) was exactly how the teacher did while in class (I found it weird too). When I asked him about it he said "It isn't that we used an unproven theorem, it's just that I didn't pay attention to the order of exercises while preparing the list".

Comment: Now I'm going to try and prove $a < b \longrightarrow a \cdot c < b \cdot c$ without using the cancelation law for multiplication.

Comment: @MikaelMello Ah, ok, yes, your instructor just had the order switched then. And to prove $c \not = 0 \rightarrow ( a < b \rightarrow a\cdot c < b \cdot c)$ is fairly straightforward: no trichotomy needed in fact ... just distribution of multiplication over addition and the definition of $<$

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach which requires defining a map:-

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$. Define set $T=\{z\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}:xz=yz \implies x=y\}$.
Instead of showing that $T=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, we define $S=T\cup\{0\}$ and show that $S=N$ by peano's inductive axiom.

Let $s:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be the successor function with properties as defined in Peano's $5$ axioms characterizing $\mathbb{N}$.

$0\in S$ (by construction).

Assume for $z\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $z\in S$, i.e., $xz=yz \implies x=y$.

Define map $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ as $f(n)=n\times s(z)$, where $z$ is a fixed number as assumed above.

It is easy to show that $f$ is injective.

(Inductive step): $x\cdot s(z) = y\cdot s(z)$

$\implies f(x)=f(y)$

$\implies x=y$ ($\because f$ is injective).

Thus, we have shown: $z\in S \implies s(z)\in S$. Hence, $S=\mathbb{N}$.